# make data type with kind *->*->* a functor

Tags: haskell

I have this type:

```
data Move a t = Emove a a
              | Move a t a
```

and I wanted to make it a functor:

```
instance Functor Move where
    fmap f (Emove x y)  = Emove (f x) (f y)
    fmap f (Move x c y) = Move (f x) c (f y)
```

but this does not compile because of the wrong kind of this type. Could someone please help me resolve this? How to supply the type `t` to this instance?

Comment: check the [functor instance for `Either a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#Either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work better if you swapped the order of the type variables to `Move`:

```
data Move t a = Emove a a | Move a t a
```

Then you can define the functor as

```
instance Functor (Move t) where
    fmap f (Emove x y) = Emove (f x) (f y)
    fmap f (Move x c y) = Move (f x) c (f y)
```

Any type that is a functor must have kind `* -> *`, that's just how it's defined.  Since you have a type that is `* -> * -> *`, you must make one of the type variables invariant under the functor (or else use a bifunctor, where the explicit purpose is to have a functor over both type variables).  Since you want the `a` to change and not the `t`, Haskell requires that the `a` type variable come last, it's just how the syntax works.  It's like with the `Either` type, the functor instance is `Functor (Either a)`, but that's a pretty arbitrary definition, it only changes values with the `Right` constructor, whereas it could have equivalently been defined for values with the `Left` constructor.  The meaning would be the same mathematically, but for consistency Haskell has enforced through syntax that the type variable that can change through the functor is the last type variable.

Comment: Sorry; I didn't read carefully enough. But I am not buying this talk of "syntax" either.

Comment: @dfeuer Is there syntax similar to `instance Functor (\a -> Move a t) where ...` that I'm not aware of?  Haskell doesn't support type level lambdas AFAIK, so this definition is enforced by syntax.

Comment: You're right that the syntax enforces the restriction, but that leads naturally to the question of why such syntax isn't added. The basic reason is that the class system doesn't support such a thing at all.

Comment: thanks. ideally, I was looking for `flip` for types.

Comment: @akonsu, you can write `newtype Flip f x y = Flip {unflip :: f y x}`, but it may be annoying to use.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider making it a [`Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) instead:

```
instance Bifunctor Move where
    bimap f g (EMove a a') = EMove (f a) (f a')
    bimap f g (Move a t a') = Move (f a) (g t) (f a')
```

The operation `first f` would then do what you wanted `fmap f` to do.

Answer (score 2):

In short: you can't. `Functor` is only parametrized on one type.

Thus, you can only make it an instance of `Functor` over the 2nd type, partially applied:

```
instance Functor (Move a) where
```

You can swap the type variables to make it parametrized over the other one in your defition.